# MySQL - create position table showing error

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.0.95.
I want to create a table called "position". 
Below are my query:

```
create table position(
position_ID int(3) not null auto_increment,
position_name varchar(30) not null,
primary key(position_ID) 
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

However, I get the below error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'position(
position_ID int(3) not null auto_increment,
position_name varchar(30) ' at line 1
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`POSITION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_position) is a function in MySQL. You'll need to provide a space between position and `(` parentheses to let MySQL know if this is not a function call but an identifier.

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

> Names of built-in functions are permitted as identifiers but may require care to be used as such. For example, COUNT is acceptable as a column name. However, by default, no whitespace is permitted in function invocations between the function name and the following ( character. This requirement enables the parser to distinguish whether the name is used in a function call or in nonfunction context.

```
create table position (
position_ID int(3) not null auto_increment,
position_name varchar(30) not null,
primary key(position_ID) 
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

You can use some other identifier to be safe:

```
create table t_position(
position_ID int(3) not null auto_increment,
position_name varchar(30) not null,
primary key(position_ID) 
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

or escape it using backticks:

```
create table `position` (
position_ID int(3) not null auto_increment,
position_name varchar(30) not null,
primary key(position_ID) 
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```